# Shortcut for if else

Tags: r, if-statement

What is the shortest way to express the folowing decission rule

```
df<-data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:5],b=1:5)
index<-df[,"a"]=="F"
if(any(index)){
  df$new<-"A"
}else{
  df$new<-"B"
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean *shortest*, is that code golf?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shortest is

```
df$new=c("B","A")[1+any(df$a=="F")]
```

More elegant is:

```
df$new <- if (any(df$a == "F")) "A" else "B"
```

or

```
df <- transform(df, new = if (any(a == "F")) "A" else "B")
```

The `ifelse` operator was suggested twice, but I would reserve it for a different type of operation:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$a == "F", "A", "B")
```

would put a `A` or a `B` on every row depending on the value of `a` in that row only (which is not what your code is currently doing.)

Comment: Is there a operator like "?" ":" as with java or php?

Comment: How 'bout `c("B","A")[1+"F"%in%df$a]`? FORE!

Comment: @BenBarnes you are a pro golfer!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe using the vectorized version `ifelse`

```
> df$new <- ifelse(any(df[,"a"]=="F"), "A", "B")
> df
  a b new
1 A 1   B
2 B 2   B
3 C 3   B
4 D 4   B
5 E 5   B
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `ifelse`:

```
df$new <- ifelse("F" %in% df$a,"A","B")
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is shorter than all the foregoing ;)

```
df$new <- LETTERS(2-any("F"%in%df$a))
```